# Testing resource cookbook with Policyfiles & ChefSpec

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec, policyfiles

This problem arises when you:

1. Write a library cookbook (i.e. it has no recipes apart from a no-op default.rb)
2. Create a `test` cookbook under `test/fixtures/cookbooks/` to exercise the library.  That is `test/fixtures/cookbooks/test/recipes/system.rb`
3. Write a ChefSpec spec that `describe 'test::system'`
4. Use Policyfiles rather than Berkshelf.

When using Berkshelf you would use `group :integration do ... end` to include the test cookbook only when running tests.

How do you write a Policyfile that only references the test cookbook when running tests?

Right now I have my policyfile always packaging the test cookbook.  Not ideal but acceptable to get something that just works in a test environment.
Not sustainable over the longer term.

Appreciate any hints, tips or incantations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two Policyfiles.

One of them contains the recipes/attributes that you would run on a "real" node. The other contains what is needed to exercise the cookbook in test kitchen.

You can specify a Policyfile path in `kitchen.rb`.

```
suites:
  - name: default
    provisioner:
      policyfile_path: policies/kitchen.rb
```